# Sprite Kit game: over world in Portrait mode but battles in Landscape mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, orientation

So far the game loads in Portrait: so the main menu is in Portrait and then the game overworld (where the player character roams around in) is also in portrait. But I need to change orientation to landscape mode when the character begins battle (also, when the player turns their phone during battle mode, I don't want the phone to change orientation & accidentally change everything back to Portrait mode or vice-versa). The battle mode is another SKScene that is presented upon certain triggers. How do I change the orientation of a newly presented SKScene to Landscape? Can I perform these changes inside individual SKScene's or only inside the View Controller? Here is the current view controller code, regarding orientation:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}


-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}
```

Here is the current code inside the battle SKScene - the one I want to force into Landscape mode (turns out very ugly since the battle scene loads in Landscape but the View Controller still thinks we're in Portrait... Another problem is that if I rotate my phone in any way, the orientation is automatically rotated. I need orientation to be fixed regrading phone movement):

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a problem because you can only manually change your app's orientation IF it is already allowed in your app settings. For example, if you only check portrait mode but later want to go to landscape mode, you can't do that.

To change orientation to, for example, landscape left you can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft  animated:NO];
```

Comment: I tried your code inside my Scene's -(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view method. The status bar doesn't rotate into LandscapeLeft. I have Portrait, Landscape Left & Landscape Right checked in my app's Targets. Even 'shouldAutorotate' returns YES. I have even tried     NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"]; The view does go to Landscape but the View Controller still thinks we're in Portrait so the entire game looks skewed/stretched.

Comment: I wonder how to force the Scene's View Controller believe the device is in a specific orientation regardless of how the physical phone is rotated...

Comment: @Krekin- Perhaps it's a case of having to call the call in the viewController instead SKScene. Try doing that by using NSNotification.

Comment: Nope. Still nothing. This is a bummer. Half the gameplay relies on battle mode yet I won't be able to use it if I can't display its Scene in Landscape mode.

Comment: @Krekin- I don't know your code so maybe this is not workable but if possible from a layout standpoint you could rotate your nodes by 90 degrees.